# How to create shell variable with dashes?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

In a Linux environment I want to create a variable name with dashes. This is possible as I can set a name like that in jenkins, for which `env` gives the output (amongst other lines):

```
variable-with-dashes=test
```

But how can do that directly on the shell? Doing

```
export variable-with-dashes=test
```

gives an error

```
-bash: export: `variable-with-dashes=test': not a valid identifier
```

In both cases the shell seems to be `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never met a Bourne-style shell that allowed - in a variable name. Only ASCII letters (of either case), _ and digits are supported, and the first character must not be a digit.

If you have a program that requires an environment variable that doesn't match the shell restrictions, launch it with the env program.

> env 'strange-name=some value' myprogram

Note that some shells (e.g. modern dash, mksh, zsh) remove variables whose name they don't like from the environment. (Shellshock has caused people to be more cautious about environment variable names, so restrictions are likely to become tighter over time, not more permissive.) So if you need to pass a variable whose name contains special character to a program, pass it directly, without a shell in between (env 'strange-name=some value' sh -c'…; myprogram' may or may not work).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-name-include-a-hyphen-or-dash

Comment: I do not understand your question. Normally, jenkings just sets environment variable with `setenv`.

Comment: The [setenv C function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv). There is no 'setenv' command.

Answer (score 0):

A [*name*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-identifier) in bash shell is defined as:

> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names.

It's not possible to use `-` in *names*.

> But how can do that directly on the shell?

I think you can write a bash builtin and in that builtin call `setenv(3)` to set your environment variable.